# SSHJ is not able to connect remote Linux server throws UserAuthException: Exhausted available authentication methods

Tags: java, authentication, ssh, sshj

I am trying to run the following Java code using [sshj](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.hierynomus/sshj/0.23.0) :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient();
    ssh.loadKnownHosts();
    ssh.connect("host", port);
    try {
        ssh.authPassword("user", "passwd");
        ssh.useCompression();

        final String src = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "test_file";
        ssh.newSCPFileTransfer().upload(new FileSystemFile(src), "/tmp/");
    } finally {
        ssh.disconnect();
        ssh.close();
    }
}
```

But it is throwing exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.UserAuthException: Exhausted available authentication methods
    at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.auth(SSHClient.java:231)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.auth(SSHClient.java:206)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.authPassword(SSHClient.java:292)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.authPassword(SSHClient.java:262)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.authPassword(SSHClient.java:246)
    at sample.SCPUpload.main(SCPUpload.java:17)
```

I can connect the host using same credentials via Putty. I am using JDK "1.8.0_151". What is wrong here?

Comment: As Hiery Nomus stated, the 'password' authentication method might not be allowed.
See what `ssh.getUserAuth().getAllowedMethods()` returns after unsuccessfull authentication, eg. in finally block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically it means that either your password is wrong, or you're not allowed to connect using the 'password' authentication method.